# Python: manipulating lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

**Problem**

I have to get elements from a text file to a list, diagonally, and from top to buttom. It should work on any dimension of the `letters.txt`. The file would look like this:

***Text file: letters.txt (thought it would be hard, I removed 'Y', and 'Z' from my original post***

```
A B C D E F
G H I J K L
M N O P Q R 
S T U V W X
```

**the lists should look like this:**

```
topButtom_List = ['AGMS', 'BHNT', 'CIOU', 'DJPV', 'EKQW', 'FLRX']

bLeftToURight = ['A', 'GB', 'MHC', 'SNID', 'TOJE', 'UPKF', 'VQL', 'WR', 'X']
```

**My current code for top to buttom:**

```
# top to buttom
topButtom_List = [] #should be ['AGMS', 'BHNT', 'CIOU', 'DJPV', 'EKQW', 'FLRX']

openFile = open("letters.txt")
for i in openFile:
    i = i.replace(" ","")
length = len(i)
openFile.close()

openFile = open("letters.txt")   
counter = 0   
for eachIterration in range(length):
    for line in openFile:
        line = line.replace(" ","")
        # counter should be added by 1 each time inner loop itterates x4, and outter loop x1.
        topButtom_List.append(line[counter]) 
    counter = counter + 1
openFile.close()
```

***What I was trying to do with the code above:***

I was trying to get the top to buttom characters from the text file and get it in a list called `topButtom_List`. I used counter to define the index that for every iteration the outer loop does, the index would be added by 1. The way I see it is, the outerloop will start, the inner loop will iterate x4 adding `AGMS` in the `topButtom_List` on the first iteration, the outer loop will iterate again and add 1 to counter. `BHNTZ` will be added on the second iteration and so on, the outer loop will iterate again and add 1 to counter.

From the text file: letters.txt
I want to populate `topButtom_List`

***Output I am getting:***

```
['A', 'G', 'M', 'S']
```

***Expected output:***

```
['AGMS', 'BHNT', 'CIOU', 'DJPV', 'EKQW', 'FLRX']
```

Comment: Interesting question! Attempt to solve it yourself, post your try with exactly what you're missing to complete it, and we'll be glad to help :)

Comment: added code. i don't know how should i ask it here, i always get a negative vote for my posts.

Comment: I corrected the vote, but just posting your code doesn't help us help you. You also need to explain what exactly isn't working with it and give examples of input and output...

Comment: corrected some variables

Comment: Are you only asking how to do the up/down or the left/right aswell

Comment: top to buttom and diagonally.

Comment: You have shown code for top to bottom, what about diagonal?

Comment: i am trying to figure out one thing at a time, those were the 2 i needed. i am concentrating on the top to bottom first.

Comment: Once you open the file its 2 lines. `letters = [line.replace(' ', '') for line in f.read().splitlines()]` and `out = [''.join(x) for x in zip(*letters)]`.

Comment: can you post a whole working code i'm sorry

Comment: @Kitty Where `f` is the file and `out` is the result. Are you able to make sense of it. I don't have an immediate solution for the 2nd one so I didnt make it an answer. Just open the file like `with open('letters.txt') as f:`, then use two lines I provided and it should all work. Check [here](https://ideone.com/U5V2tN)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

field = """A B C D E F
           G H I J K L
           M N O P Q R
           S T U V W X"""

arr = [col.split(' ') for col in [row.strip() for row in field.split('\n')]]
len_x, len_y = len(arr[0]), len(arr)
len_all = len_x + len_y - 1
lines, groups = [], []

for i in range(len_all):
    start = (i, 0) if i < len_y else (len_y-1, i-len_y+1)
    end = (0, i) if i < len_x else (i-len_x+1, len_x-1)
    lines.append([start, end])

print('List of start and end points: ', lines)

for start, end in lines:
    group = ''
    for i in range(len_x):
        y, x = start[0] - i, start[1] + i
        if y >= 0 and y < len(arr) and x < len(arr[y]):
            group += arr[y][x]
        else:
            groups.append(group)
            break

print(groups)
```

Returns

```
List of start and end points:  [[(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(1, 0), (0, 1)],
[(2, 0), (0, 2)], [(3, 0), (0, 3)], [(3, 1), (0, 4)], [(3, 2), (0, 5)], 
[(3, 3), (1, 5)], [(3, 4), (2, 5)], [(3, 5), (3, 5)]]
```

and

```
['A', 'GB', 'MHC', 'SNID', 'TOJE', 'UPKF', 'VQL', 'WR', 'X']
```

Comment: thanks! that was useful! is there any way to do it without break?

Comment: Hi, I am having a problem with the code, if I use a different dimension of texts on the field variable in your code, it only gets part of it and the others just prints an empty space on a list.